# How to strip apostrophes?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here definiton:

> The apostrophe token filter strips all characters after an apostrophe,
>   including the apostrophe itself.

Trying to strip apostrophes and characters after them. When there is only one apostrophe, filter doesn't strip anything at all. Also when there is multiple sequential apostrophes, it splits concerned words **but do not strip anything after apostrophes**. Clearly I must be missing something.

Input with single apostrophe:

```
POST localhost:9200/_analyze?
{
    "filter": ["apostrophe"],
    "text": "apple banana'orange kiwi"
}
```

Output

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "apple",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "banana'orange",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "kiwi",
      "start_offset": 20,
      "end_offset": 24,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Input with multiple sequential apostrophes.

```
{
    "filter": ["apostrophe"],
    "text": "apple banana''orange kiwi"
}
```

Output

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "apple",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "banana",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "orange",
      "start_offset": 14,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "kiwi",
      "start_offset": 21,
      "end_offset": 25,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you, you want to just wipe out apostrophes? or split by them and remove them?

Comment: I want to strip apostrophe and characters after it. Updated the question.

Comment: what about trying https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a token filter alone it won't work because the `standard` analyzer will kick in and tokenize your input and the `apostrophe` token filter will be ignored. If you add the `explain` parameter you get more info about what's going on:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty&filter=apostrophe&explain' -d "apple banana'orange kiwi"
{
  "detail" : {
    "custom_analyzer" : false,
    "analyzer" : {
      "name" : "standard",
      "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "apple",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 5,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 0,
        "bytes" : "[61 70 70 6c 65]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      }, {
        "token" : "banana'orange",
        "start_offset" : 6,
        "end_offset" : 19,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 1,
        "bytes" : "[62 61 6e 61 6e 61 27 6f 72 61 6e 67 65]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      }, {
        "token" : "kiwi",
        "start_offset" : 20,
        "end_offset" : 24,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 2,
        "bytes" : "[6b 69 77 69]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the above was just using a `standard` analyzer.

To fix this, you simply need to specify at least a tokenizer. If you take the `standard` tokenizer then it works as expected. And you can see that you now have a custom analyzer using the `standard` tokenizer and the `apostrophe` token filter which can now do its job properly.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty&tokenizer=standard&filter=apostrophe&explain' -d "apple banana'orange kiwi"
{
  "detail" : {
    "custom_analyzer" : true,
    "charfilters" : [ ],
    "tokenizer" : {
      "name" : "standard",
      "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "apple",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 5,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 0,
        "bytes" : "[61 70 70 6c 65]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      }, {
        "token" : "banana'orange",
        "start_offset" : 6,
        "end_offset" : 19,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 1,
        "bytes" : "[62 61 6e 61 6e 61 27 6f 72 61 6e 67 65]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      }, {
        "token" : "kiwi",
        "start_offset" : 20,
        "end_offset" : 24,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 2,
        "bytes" : "[6b 69 77 69]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      } ]
    },
    "tokenfilters" : [ {
      "name" : "apostrophe",
      "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "apple",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 5,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 0,
        "bytes" : "[61 70 70 6c 65]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      }, {
        "token" : "banana",
        "start_offset" : 6,
        "end_offset" : 19,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 1,
        "bytes" : "[62 61 6e 61 6e 61]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      }, {
        "token" : "kiwi",
        "start_offset" : 20,
        "end_offset" : 24,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 2,
        "bytes" : "[6b 69 77 69]",
        "positionLength" : 1
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```